# Print entire feed with json?

Tags: jquery, json

Im working with the code below from here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
    });
  });
```

How can I print out the entire feed. The following prints nothing:

```
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("content").html(data);
    });
  });
```

On my page I have 2 divs, one with and ID of images and the other with an ID of content.
Thanks

UPDATE - Ive fixed the missing hash but the first example still works but the 2nd does not.

http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/json/1.html

http://smartpeopletalkfast.co.uk/json/2.html

I need to change the feed to a youtube one so I thought printing the entire contence as the simplest start to this.
Thanks

Comment: What is `content` is it an ID or a class? Remember to prepend them with # and . respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [this](http://frazsundal.blogspot.com/2011/03/understand-and-implement-jquery-getjson.html) blog post it shows how to get images from flickr api using jquery getJson

Answer (score 0):

The second block of code is replacing the html of `content` on every loop and appears to be missing a hash or period in the selector. I imagine something along the lines of -

```
$("#content").append(data);
```

...would do the trick. That being said, if you are just trying to view the JSON being returned why not just use chrome developer tools or firebug?

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("#content").append(item);
    });
  });
```